# How to make select list and input text field read only for preventing editing

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am developing an oracle APEX application.

I created the form with master details form. How to make select list and input field to read only on tabular form (Add Row Section) when the status value is selected "Closed" or "Cancelled".

I have searched on stackoverflow but I could not find any related question about that.
Please give me idea about that ? Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Probably half a dozen ways to do this.

Add column in your sql (that isn't displayed to user) that calculates literal value of 'readonly' or null, depending on your status column value. Give it a column alias of 'readonly'

```
CASE status IN ('Closed','Cancelled') THEN 'readonly' END AS readonly_col
```

Edit your Status column and add to 'Element CSS Classes' : #READONLY_COL#

(hash tag surrounding your column alias)

Comment: Thank you. I am a beginner of APEX. would you show me how about the sql statement for adding readonly column (calculate literal value of "Readonly"). and whether add Element CSS Classes' : #READONLY# to every selet list and input field. please help.

Comment: how about this : decode(STATUS, 'Closed', ReadOnly, 'Cancelled', ReadOnly) "READONLY". Is it corrected for adding a column in my SQL?

Comment: DECODE's a little old, use:
CASE status IN ('Closed','Cancelled') THEN 'readonly' END

Comment: you would add the css class to every field you want read only

Comment: thanks,ScottWe. What statement i should place on CSS Clase to corresponding to CASE status IN ('Closed','Cancelled') THEN 'readonly' END ?

Comment: I want to make sure that my case, the status value is on Master table "Order".P_STATUS, now i want to make read-only on all input fields on ADD ROW Section when P_STATUS is either Closed or Cancelled.

Comment: Hi ScottWe, I'm still unsuccessful about that. Would you mind going into my workspace to check for what did I do wrong? If okay, i will provide my login information to you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a classic report to the page with the same columns. Render the tabular form when the status is not close or cancelled, and render the classic report when it is by using the condition on both regions.

Answer (score 0):

```
For LOV/Select List, here is a simple solution for you
// disable:
$('#P123_ITEM_CNT').attr('readonly', true);
$('#P123_ITEM_CNT').css('pointer-events','none');
$('#P123_ITEM_CNT').css('opacity','.5');
$('#P123_ITEM_CNT').off('keydown');
//enable:
$('#P123_ITEM_CNT').attr('readonly', false);
$('#P123_ITEM_CNT').css('pointer-events','');
$('#P123_ITEM_CNT').css('opacity','inherit');
$("#P123_ITEM_CNT").on('keydown');
```